# DeepLab: InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D;

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

While trying out the demo of [DeepLab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) (a [link to the demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/deeplab_demo.ipynb)) for semantic image segmentation I got the following error:

```
running deeplab on image https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/img/image1.jpg?raw=true...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-c8336c0ddcd6> in <module>()
     25 
     26 image_url = IMAGE_URL or _SAMPLE_URL % SAMPLE_IMAGE
---> 27 run_visualization(image_url)

<ipython-input-4-c8336c0ddcd6> in run_visualization(url)
     19 
     20   print 'running deeplab on image %s...' % url
---> 21   resized_im, seg_map = MODEL.run(orignal_im)
     22 
     23   vis_segmentation(resized_im, seg_map)

<ipython-input-2-c1ac870c1e95> in run(self, image)
     49     batch_seg_map = self.sess.run(
     50         self.OUTPUT_TENSOR_NAME,
---> 51         feed_dict={self.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME: [np.asarray(resized_image)]})
     52     seg_map = batch_seg_map[0]
     53     return resized_image, seg_map

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    887     try:
    888       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 889                          run_metadata_ptr)
    890       if run_metadata:
    891         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1118     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1119       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1120                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1121     else:
   1122       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1315     if handle is None:
   1316       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
-> 1317                            options, run_metadata)
   1318     else:
   1319       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1334         except KeyError:
   1335           pass
-> 1336       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1337 
   1338   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: MobilenetV2/Conv/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sub_7, MobilenetV2/Conv/weights). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: MobilenetV2/Conv/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sub_7, MobilenetV2/Conv/weights)]]

Caused by op u'MobilenetV2/Conv/Conv2D', defined at:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 478, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 281, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 232, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 397, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-9b57c985b5f0>", line 27, in <module>
    MODEL = DeepLabModel(download_path)
  File "<ipython-input-2-c1ac870c1e95>", line 31, in __init__
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 313, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: MobilenetV2/Conv/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sub_7, MobilenetV2/Conv/weights). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
     [[Node: MobilenetV2/Conv/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](sub_7, MobilenetV2/Conv/weights)]]
```

My current config is 12GB RAM, 4GB GPU but I don't think it's an issue with the hardware requirements, as I am only testing the model

Tensorflow version is 1.4.0

Comment: It worked after upgrading Tensorflow version to >1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "arbitrary dilations" is added by tensorflow 1.5.0-rc1, so the version of Tensorflow should be higher than this.

Go to this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?after=v1.6.0) and search 'dilations', you will see.